# Open a GridContextMenu on a button click

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

We have a column with a collapsed overflow MenuBar on a grid with plenty of items and the rendering performance was really terrible, even using lazy loading.

We replaced it with a GridContextMenu and the grid is loading much faster now. But the users will miss the menu bar button to invoke the menu by clicking on it. I'm trying to find a way to trigger the opening of Context Menu from a native button render column.

Is there a way to open the context menu programatically or to emulate the right click on a grid row?

I've tried to implement the menubar with a LitRenderer but ContextMenu seemed a lot easier and maintainable. The only missing part is to be able to invoke it by clicking on some element in a column.

Something like this:

```
grid.addColumn(new NativeButtonRenderer<>(
        item -> "..." ,
        clickedItem -> {
            openContextMenu(item) // how to implement openContextMenu?
        })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that your `ContextMenu` is `menu` and you have a `menuButton` of type `Button`, this is, how it is done:

```
menu.setTarget(menuButton);
menu.setOpenOnClick(true);
```

Comment: Let me explain better, Id like to have a column using a NativeButtonRenderer. Unless I missing something to use a Button I would haver to use a ComponentRenderer which is what I want to avoid due to poor performance. Maybe I'm wrong but even if I used a button, the setTarget would associate the ContextMenu with the last rendered button woudn't it? The idea was to click ona button in a cell and open the contextmenu as if I had right clicked on thet row.

Comment: well it turns out that after I tested your suggestion, creating a button and a individual ContextMenu in each redered cell is not nearly as heavy as using menubar. So it suits me after all. Thanks!

Comment: @TiagoSchumann If a question does not answer your question, you don't have to accept it. It will mislead others with the same question. If you found your own solution feel free to add your own answer. If you have to decided, that you will work-around the problem for now, keep the question open.

Comment: @cfrick, although the answer was not exactly what I asked at first, it led me to a valid alternative path to avoid the  performance problem I was facing when using a menubar on a grid column. My original  question was based on  the premise that a component renderer with a vaadin button triggering the contex menu on a grid would suffer from the same performance issues as the menu bar does, but the anwer made me test it and it proved that the premise was wrong.